# Add Widget Issue in Blogger template

Tags: html, widget, blogs, blogger, blogspot

I have created a custom template using HTML and CSS. There are sections with "Add Widget" Option.
Now whenever a widget is adding the template source code is not showing the widget code. After adding the widget the layout shows the widget added. But on refreshing the layout page, there is no widget.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you sure you are refreshing after clicking "save" ?

Comment: yes... but anyhow the issue is resolved to some extent.. thankx